# Get first and second cell of every HTML table row

Tags: .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get just some specific cells in each row using HTMLAgilityPack.

```
foreach (HtmlNode row in ContentNode.SelectNodes("descendant::tr"))
{
    //Do something to first cell
    //Do something to second cell
}
```

There are more cells, and each cell needs some specialized treatment. I guess there's a way to do this using XPath, but I'm fairly useless at that. Is there maybe something like

```
var cell1 = row.SelectSingleNode("descendant::td:first");
```

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a one-liner XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get each first cell that is a child of a row, you can do the following:

```
// from row
var firstCell = row.SelectSingleNode("td[1]");

// each first cell in a table (note: tbody is not always there)
var allFirstCells = table.SelectNodes("tbody/tr/td[1]");
```

In other words, use square brackets and the cell-number you wish to select. An exception is the last cell, which you can get using `last()` as follows:

```
// from row
var lastCell = row.SelectSingleNode("td[last()]");

// each last cell in a table
var allLastCells = table.SelectNodes("tbody/tr/td[last()]");
```

If you want to get the cell next to a current cell, you can do something like this:

```
// from row
var firstCell = row.SelectSingleNode("td[1]");
var siblingCell = firstCell.SelectSingleNode("./following-sibling::td");
```

You may wish to check the return values for null, which means you either have a typo, or the DOM tree you loaded does not contain the cell you asked for.

Comment: Sweet! Is that just "regular" XPath, or is it some special concoction from the htmlagilitypack-dudes?

Comment: @peirix: it is totally regular XPath. HtmlAgility doesn't add anything special. They create a .NET DOM, and the SelectNodes uses Microsoft's .NET implementation of XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

**Instead of**:

```
descendant::tr
```

**use**:

```
descendant::tr/td[not(position() >2)]
```

Comment: +1, nice & quick solution. But for *"each cell needs special treatment"* (OQ) the business logic will need a `mod 2` or similar and it becomes problematic in cases where not each row contains > 1 cells.